# Profiling React app in Chrome DevTools - Profiling not supported

Tags: reactjs, profiling

When i try to profile the production build of my app, in the `Profile` tab of the Chrome DevTools, i get the following message:

```
Profiling not supported.
Profiling support requires either a development or production-profiling build of React v16.5+.
```

(my React version is 16.8)
How can i fix that?

I'm using Webpack4, and adding this to my config file as suggested by the official React docs didn't help:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
      'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What's your version of react-dom (16.8.0?) and scheduler packages?

Comment: The project has `react-dom 16.12.0`. Couldn't find a `scheduler` in the `package.json`..

Comment: Can you run npm ls scheduler and tell me the output?

Comment: You will need ^0.18.0 scheduler version with that react-dom version and then we can talk about the config file

Comment: `npm ls scheduler` shows i have `scheduler@0.18.0 ` under `react-dom@16.12.0`.

Comment: Your config looks good given the packages versions, i think you are just missing the scheduler installation (please be sure you install the exact same version)

Comment: So i need to install `scheduler` on its own? regardless of the one i have under `react-dom`?

Comment: Yes, it's the safest way to ensure the scheduler is the exact version react-dom needs:

https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/25e6233aeb1b4f0cdb8d8366e54a3977#troubleshooting

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working :(

Comment: did you build your project with yarn build --profile or the npm equivalent? That's a requirement for enabling profiling in production apps

Comment: Yes i ran `npm run build -- --profile`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the alone "--" do. I'm out of ideas

Comment: I tried both with and without the `--`.. many thanks anyway for you help!

Answer (score 18):

By default, React doesn't include profiling in **production** builds, you'll need to add that by using the [Profiler API](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html).

The Profiler API provides a component which takes an id (string), and an onRender callback as arguments. You can wrap any part of your React tree with this component and get profiling info from it, though it won't be available in the DevTools, and thus won't have the nice flame chart. It would look something like this:

```
<Profiler id="MyComponent" onRender={onRenderCallback}>
  <MyComponent {...props} />
</Profiler>
```

The `onRender` callback does provide some neat info though that you could send off to an API endpoint:

```
function onRenderCallback(
  id, // the "id" prop of the Profiler tree that has just committed
  phase, // either "mount" (if the tree just mounted) or "update" (if it re-rendered)
  actualDuration, // time spent rendering the committed update
  baseDuration, // estimated time to render the entire subtree without memoization
  startTime, // when React began rendering this update
  commitTime, // when React committed this update
  interactions // the Set of interactions belonging to this update
) {
  // Aggregate or log render timings...
}
```

This ☝️ came directly from the React docs linked above.

Keep in mind that any component you add, adds CPU and memory overhead, so you should really only use the React.Profiler when needed. Ideally you should be profiling your components and finding bottlenecks in development mode.

It's worth noting that the config you included above for `'react-dom/profiling'` and `'scheduler/tracing-profiling'` is required during your build process to get this React.Profiler working.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: That also didn't work, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914761/react-profiler-error-expected-a-string-or-a-class-function-but-got-undefined

Comment: Here's a codesandbox of this working: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-meadow-q9w7v.

If you've got a reproduce-able example, that might help. Otherwise, working carefully through the docs I've linked above is a good start.

Comment: I have no doubt it's working, the issue is to get it to work with my webpack build. You can also refer to the other question i posted in my comment above which is more recent and that's what i'm currently trying to solve.

Comment: Here's a blog post by Kent C. Dodds, where he goes into some detail on getting the build up and running to profile a production app https://kentcdodds.com/blog/profile-a-react-app-for-performance.

In this he talks about what you'll need to do in your webpack config, though his example is using Create-React-App. Are you using your own webpack configuration or are you using something like CRA?