# I want to use profiler of react developer tools in my built website. but it says "Profiling not supported."

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, react-devtools

I want to use profiler of react dev tools.
I built my project with gh-pages(^6.1.0).

```
"scripts": {
    
    "build": "react-scripts build",
   
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

I just command

```
npm run deploy
```

and publish my web site.

My react version is

```
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.61",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

You can see i use React 18.2.0 version.

But react dev tools says "Profiling not supported.
Profiling support requires either a development or profiling build of React v16.5+.

Learn more at reactjs.org/link/profiling."

Why did this issue occur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profiling React app in Chrome DevTools - Profiling not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555114/profiling-react-app-in-chrome-devtools-profiling-not-supported)

Comment: thx you for search similar question.